# Create .deb package from revision tag for a git url

Tags: git, bash, permissions, deb

created the following bash script to create a .deb package from a git url & revision tag:https://github.com/GlassGhost/GitDeb

I tested it with:

> bash /path/to/GitDeb.sh git://repo.or.cz/tinycc.git tcc 0.9.26
>   release_0_9_26

but on calling line 36 of https://github.com/GlassGhost/GitDeb/blob/d0c24db46244cc34c0cffded57903fddb290d790/GitDeb.sh

```
fakeroot checkinstall --install=no --pkgname="$PkgName" --pkgversion="$PkgVersion" -y -D make install
```

it fails with the following:

```
Installing with make install...

========================= Installation results ===========================
make -C lib native
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/owner/Documents/GitDeb/tcc/lib'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `native'.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/owner/Documents/GitDeb/tcc/lib'
mkdir -p "/usr/local/bin"
install -m755 tcc "/usr/local/bin"
install: cannot create regular file ‘/usr/local/bin/tcc’: Permission denied
make: *** [install] Error 1

****  Installation failed. Aborting package creation.
```

Comment: Your script works for me and I don't get why you would have such error. Please paste the complete output of your script on http://pastebin.com/ and share the link here.

Comment: @janos I tried the answer below adding fstrans, still getting an error link in that comment

Comment: That error is easy to fix, create the directory `/usr/local/share/doc`  and rerun your script. If you get another error, post it again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`checkinstall` documentation](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man8/checkinstall.8.html) suggests using `--fstrans`. So use this flag.

**Update:** I've downloaded your repo and run your code in an lxc container. Just adding `--fstrans` definitely allows me to create a complete deb by running your command.

`fakeroot` fakes some file operations but it does *not* allow the command it launches to install things where permissions are needed. That's why `--fstrans` is needed.

**ETA:** The command `mkdir -p "/usr/local/share/doc/tcc"` may fail. That's because the directory `/usr/local/share/doc` does not *already* exist when `checkinstall` is started. Yes, `-p` means create all the parents so it should work but for some reason `--fstrans` is unable to handle it. The solution is to precreate `/usr/local/share/doc/` before running `checkinstall`:

```
sudo mkdir /usr/local/share/doc
```

This is something I would do *manually* before trying to build. Just like I had to manually install packages with `apt-get` so that the build would work. (Adding a check in the script for the existence of this directory would be helpful though for other folks who may run your script.)

Comment: updated github trying it with --fstrans, now I'm getting a different error. https://gist.github.com/GlassGhost/7628249

Comment: I added ./configure --prefix=/usr, fixed the new error I was having. https://github.com/GlassGhost/GitDeb/commit/3367429b83f2fe75e31ff976b5817a9263668aed Question marked as solved!!! Looking back I should have read more into checkinstall documentation. Can't believe I spent 200 rep, but really; I think it was worth it.

Comment: Regarding ``--prefix``, I thought about that but I had decided that you already had decided you wanted it where it was installing. :)